# How to write one line window events in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking for three window events in my script:

```
window.onload = updateData;
window.onresize = updateData;
window.onscroll = updateData;
```

How could I optimize my code and write this in one line? I tried:

```
window.onload || window.onresize || window.onscroll = updateData;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what about `window.onload = window.onresize = window.onscroll = updateData;` ?

Comment: @RafH you should have posted it as answer, it's right

Comment: "How could I optimize my code and write this in one line?" I wouldn't call this optimization, this is style preference. I would argue the way you wrote it in your question is more readable than a single line.

Comment: @ssorallen - it contains less characters? :) Also my wording is pretty poor so I might have used the incorrect term.

Comment: @easwee Don't sacrifice readability for what you think is an optimization. In this case, a minifier would do this work for you while you get to keep your code more verbose and understandable.

Comment: @ssorallen - well we have comments for that? If I can write same thing with less characters I guess it's better if it's not slower. I will minify the code anyway later and strip out all comments.

Comment: @easwee I meant a good minifer could convert your original code into a single liner like you are doing manually. 3 successive assignments of the same variable can safely be replaced by a minifier to a single line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.onload = window.onresize = window.onscroll = updateData;
```

If this was a normal variable assignation such as: 
 `a = 1`  this would return 1,

so in `b = a = 1` , the b var receives the value 1 from the previous assignation and the current on returns 1 too as result.

On the other hand I would suggest that the updateData function would implement some race condition control to prevent that routine to be running simultaneously.

Comment: Cool this works - could you explain a bit just what is the logic behind using '=' ?

Comment: @easwee The `=` operator 1) evaluates to the result of the assignment, and; 2) is left-associative. It is equivalent to `window.onload = (window.onresize = (window.onscroll = updateData))`

Comment: Er, = means equals. onload equals onresize equals onscroll equals updateData. Consider this the same as `onscroll=updateData; onresize=onscroll; onload=onresize;`

Comment: @enhzflep No, in most programming languages `==` means 'is equal to'. `=` assigns whatever is (returned/defined) on the right to the variable that is on the left.

Comment: @enhzflep It's more equivalent to: `onscroll = updateDate; onresize = updateData; onload = updateData;`, since assignment returns the right side.

Comment: @Sumurai8 - Re: `==` yup, it is in every language that I bother with. That why I didn't write "is equal to" - I merely wrote the words that I say mentally. If you read "a = 5" as 'assign 5 to a', that's no different to me thinking "a equals 5", though one is more verbose. Thanks for reminding me to be more particular with terminology. :)

Comment: @Paulpro - oops! Thanks for the clarification. Going to have a look at how gcc and vs implement that construct. I'll come back if it's any different to your assertion. :)

Comment: @enhzflep The biggest problem I have with calling it 'equals' is if you have something like `a = new ClassName` and `b = a`. I believe in that case both a and b point to the same ClassName object, but are two different variables with 2 seperate memory positions. For something like `a = 1` I guess it is somewhat the same, as the memory position contains a representation of 1, rather than a pointer to an object. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of properties to assign, then

```
['onload', 'onresize', 'onscroll'].forEach(function(x){window[x] = updateData})
```

will eventually be shorter.

Comment: `var w= window; w.onload = w.onresize = w.onscroll = updateData;` ;)

Comment: +1 This will be eventually be shorter (even with @Edorka's aliasing of the window object) and it's more readable to me.

Comment: Tried this method too and it also works - I guess if I had more than 5 events I would definately use this since it is much more clearer and it would get shorter. Upvoted!